# How to loop through a dataframe and create directories python

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to iterate through a dataframe and create a directory for each element in 'source_name'. my code below works fine but only creates the first directory from the first element. How do i make this happen for every element in the list

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

ds_data = pd.read_csv("feeds_and_urls.csv")

feeds = pd.DataFrame(ds_data)
feeds['source_name'].replace(' ', '_', regex=True, inplace=True)

for index, row in feeds.iterrows():
   print(row['source_name'], row['url'])
   os.mkdir(row['source_name'])
   break
```

Answer (score 0):

solution was to simply remove the 'break' command at the bottom